# oracle 11g installation on ubuntu 16.04 sysctl permission denied?

Tags: sysctl, oracle-database, oracle

I am trying to install oracle 11g on ubuntu 16.04
after setting oracle 11g xe kernel parameters successfully

```
# Oracle 11g XE kernel parameters  

fs.file-max=6815744  

net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65000  

kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128 

kernel.shmmax=536870912
```

I used 
`sudo service procps start`
which doesn't give any response like 
`procps start/stop`
and when I use command
`sudo sysctl -q fs.file-max`
It shows the default number
`383667` and not the one I set

and when I set explicitly
`sysctl -w fs.file-max=6815744`

I get error
`sysctl: permission denied on key 'fs.file-max'`

Answer (score 0):

To address the title question: you did not use `sudo`, on that command.

Comment: I did use sudo. Actually I solved the problem by executing the command 
 "sudo service procps restart"